# javascript - how to restart a function from inside it?

Tags: javascript, function, restart

How do I restart a function calling it from inside the same function?

Comment: The answers below are sufficient, you just need to take care to have a condition where the function is **not** going to be restarted so you don't get caught in a loop.

Answer (score 11):

Just call the function again, then return, like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  //stuff...
  if(condition) {
    myFunction();
    return;
  }
}
```

The `if` part is optional of course, I'm not certain of your *exact* application here.  If you need the return value, it's one line, like this: `return myFunction();`

Comment: Hmmm I would not say that the "if" part is optional.  Without it, you would end up calling myFunction recursively until overflowing the stack.

Comment: @Eric - Not necessarily....he could have an if/abort style before hitting this, could go either way.

Answer (score 3):

Well its recommended to use a named function now instead of arguments.callee which is still valid, but seemingly deprecated in the future.

```
// Named function approach
function myFunction() {
    // Call again
    myFunction();
}

// Anonymous function using the future deprecated arguments.callee
(function() {
    // Call again
    arguments.callee();
)();
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean recursion?

```
function recursion() {
    recursion();

}
```

or

```
var doSomething = function recursion () {
     recursion();   
}
```

**Note** Using this named anonymous function is not advised because of a longstanding bug in IE. Thanks to [lark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282175/lark) for this.

Of course this is just an example...

Comment: It is very inadvisable to use a named anonymous function, since there is a bug that has persisted throughout all versions of IE that leaks it into the global namespace overriding any functions named there that are the same.

Comment: @lark Correct, maybe I should leave a note. Thank you.